# implement waiting timer using only the standard library

Tags: c++, timer, c++14

What completely standard C++ ways exist to implement a waiting timer? That is, code that will trigger a timer callback now and then and will wait for a timeout to occur (not waste any, or very little, CPU cycles). There must be a finite number of ways to do this with `std::`. Currently I am using `<thread>` and the timeout feature of the [condition variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for). But is seems wasteful to have to spawn a thread for each timer.

Comment: Well, if the problem is spawning the thread for each timer, then you can have one thread that's handling all the timers. You can keep an ordered list of timers and call the callback for each one of them once it reaches the programmed timeout

Comment: @redobot that means looping, which consumes CPU.

Comment: It will depend on your implementation. If you keep the list ordered then you can perform new timer insertions in O(log(n)) and you have just to check for the first timer in the list to see if it's actually fired or not. Any way, I think you should not care about the performance until you hit some problem (avoid premature optimization).

Comment: @redobot It's a personal preference. I used to work a lot with student workers and one of the symptoms of a student worker at work was a huge number of threads. 100 timers = 100 threads, I don't like it.

Comment: Sorry, but my comment was to use only one thread to keep track of all the timers (we do use a similar implementation on real-time software and it works without problems). To enhance the performance you should keep the list of timers ordered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::this_thread::sleep_for()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) and [`std::this_thread::sleep_until()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until) are useful but unless you're spawning a new thread, you cannot do any other work at the same time.